# Segfault with x86 code

Tags: assembly, x86

I am working on a c to x86 compiler and actually i am generating some code lines but i have a segmentation fault when i try to launch it and i can't figure out the source of the error.
Here is the code :

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .text            
    .globl main
    .type main, @function  
main:                        
    pushl   %ebp                     
    movl    %esp,   %ebp               
    subl    $32,    %esp             
    movl    $2, %eax                        
    movl    %eax,   -4(%ebp) 
    movl    $3, %eax                         
    movl    %eax,   -8(%ebp) 
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax        
    popl    %ecx         
    addl    %ecx,   %eax  
    pushl   %eax        
    movl    -8(%ebp), %eax                         
    movl    %eax,   -12(%ebp)
```

The segfault seems to appear at the first instruction "pushl %ebp"

Comment: You should use the debugger to figure out the problem.  In fact, you shouldn't be attempting to write assembler unless you're intimately familiar with how to use the debugger.

Comment: What happens when you single-step it in the debugger?

Comment: Also, it does some data moving, a subtract, some push/pop then what?  Is that it?  What is supposed to happen after the first 10 nanoseconds when the 'movl %eax, -12(%ebp)' has been executed?

Comment: We don't even know if it gets to main:

Comment: I commented the code line by line and yes it gets to main, the segfault is produced when reading the first pushl instruction

Comment: If you're segfaulting on a `push`, that sounds like you don't have a valid stack set up.  Are you using your platform's `start` implementation?

Comment: 'I commented the code line by line' - can't see any comments at all.

Comment: 'yes it gets to main, the segfault is produced when reading the first pushl instruction'.  Unless you give us all details of any debugging done so far, we're just wasting our time going over the same ground that you have already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming what you've told us is correct, there are roughly two explanations of what might be going wrong:

Disregarding the completely "out there" explanations, like "your CPU is broken", a segfault on a `push` instruction can occur for two reasons:

- the stack is not set up correctly, so that the instruction is trying to push data to a read-only or unmapped address, or
- the memory page containing the instruction *itself* is not marked as executable.

From the information given, it's impossible to say which of these two is causing the problem.
You'll have to determine that. (Or give us some more information, for example, about how the code is being executed)

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i figured out the problem, but i still do not understand it,my  subl    $32,%esp needed to be  subl    $16,%esp . But there is a new segfault appearing now when trying to execute  popl    %ecx

Comment: What is there to pop anyway?  You have created a local stack frame by subbing 20 from SP and then you pop.. what? into ecx?